# error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert data in phpMyAdmin but returns me an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO utilizadores(nome, login, password, email, tipoacesso) VALUE' at line 1.
```

<`

```
//variáveis de estabelecer ligação à base de dados
$hostDB = "localhost";
$userDB = "root";
$passDB = "";
$nameDB = "sistemaimportacao";

//conexão à base de dados
$connectDB = mysql_connect($hostDB,$userDB,$passDB, $nameDB) or die ("não foi possível conectar: ".mysql_error());

class users{

    private $_login;
    private $_password;
    private $_tipoacesso;
    private $_nome;

    public function __construct($login, $password,$tipoacesso,$nome){
        $this->_login=$login;
        $this->_password=$password;
        $this->_tipoacesso=$tipoacesso;
        $this->_nome=$nome;
    }

    public function create(){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(login, password, tipoacesso, nome) 
VALUES ('$this->_login', '$this->_password', '$this->_tipoacesso','$this->_nome')";
        echo $sql;
        mysql_query($sql);
    }

}

$reg = new users("abc", "qwerty", "1", "edgar");
$reg->create();
```

?>`

I am sure that the name of table and fields are correct.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used keywords in your column names (`password` is a keyword), encapsulate them in backward ticks to avoid ambiguity.

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `password`, `tipoacesso`, `nome`) 
VALUES ('$this->_login', '$this->_password', '$this->_tipoacesso','$this->_nome')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting quotes around your `password` value, it is likely not an integer data type:

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores(nome, login, password, email, tipoacesso) 
VALUES ('Edgar', 'apolo90', '123456','edgar@edgar.pt',1)
```

Comment: @user1752753 Please provide your schema.